# How to document legacy code (shell scripts)?

Tags: project-management, documentation, scripting, legacy, legacy-code

I got involved into a project where we are taking over a bunch of legacy code. Code is basically shell scripts and PL/SQL packages/procedures/functions. There is no documentation how the code works and there is also no comments on the shell scripts. I was thinking that first thing to do is to get an understanding of the dependencies of the code, how to scripts call each other and so on. Do you have any suggestions what would be the best way to document the dependencies between scripts and PL/SQL code? What would be the most suggested tool for this (for diagrams, perhaps)?